# How to force github/gitlab markdown to keep a rel="me" anchor attribute?

Tags: github, gitlab, markdown, mastodon

How to force github/gitlab markdown to keep a rel="me" anchor attribute?

```
Consider the very simple markdown fragment.

<!-- Testing with ghostwriter -->
<!-- Test link rendering with the following six lines -->
<!-- First line. -->
<!-- example.com/@user -->
<!-- https//example.com/@user -->
<!-- https://example.com/@user -->
<!-- <a rel="me" href="https://example.com/@user" target="_blank">User</a> -->
<!-- Last line. -->

First line.

example.com/@user1

http://example.com/@user2

https://example.com/@user3

<a rel="me nofollow" href="https://example.com/@user4" target="_blank">User</a>

Last line.
```

There are two goals for using a single markdown file (*.md) in a repository:
1 help verify one or many Mastodon links (hence the rel="me" attribute) and
2 provide readers with a link from Mastodon to view some source code.

It doesn't matter if it is a single markdown file or a wiki file as both seem to use the same markdown processor.

Also it would be nice if one file could be used by many users, say 100, to help verify a Mastodon link for a specific project.
Without the rel="me" attribute in the anchor element the Mastodon verification will not work.

The markdown in github and gitlab strips out the rel="me" attribute while in ghostwriter and codeberg the rel="me" gets translated into something like rel="me nofollow ..." but the "me" is present for the Mastodon verification process.

Question: does anyone know how to force github and gitlab to keep the rel="me" atribute when the anchor html element is rendered in a web page?

Using a raw view mode will help with the verification but does not provide a link to easily view source code files.

Hopefully someone who knows much more about github/gitlab markdown than I do can help.

Thank you.

I was hoping that github/gitlab would work more like codeberg in terms of link rendering.
It would be unrealistic to expect everyone to switch to codeberg.

By pasting the sample code (above) into various code repositories people can see for themselves what is going on.
I have tested markdown files and wikis in github, gitlab and codeberg but only codeberg worked as I wanted.
Maybe there is some obsure tweak not listed in the github/gitlab markdown documentation that will preserve the rel="me" attribute?

Comment: This requires a change on GitLab’s side. See https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/25404